# Capture form submit event WITHOUT Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to submit a form to an endpoint but cannot do this with AJAX due to CORS headers that I do not control.

Im currently doing this by rendering a hidden iframe and targeting the submission there. But I am still not able to capture the event (Im guessing because it's within the iframe's scope??)

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" action="www.example.com/submission-endpoint" target="hiddenframe" >
    // ... form fields ...
</form>
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="hiddenframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("my-form").submit(function(e){

    console.log(e); // does not print to console
});
```

I'm open to other implementations but I'd (1) like to know why the form submit event is not accessible (nothing printed to console) and (2) how I can submit this form *without* using XHR/AJAX yet still fire a callback function and do some stuff on submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) like to know why the form submit event is not accessible (nothing printed to console)

The `submit()` method is used to *trigger* a form submission programmatically.

To listen for events, use `addEventListener("submit", your_function);`.

> (2) how I can submit this form without using XHR/AJAX yet still fire a callback function and do some stuff on submission.

The above combined with a regular submit button will do the job.

Note that while you can detect the request from the user to submit the form, you won't be able to read the response as the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will still apply.

Comment: thank you! part of the reason the event listener wasn't working for me is because the submit buttons on our site is actually an anchor tag (for styling reasons) so the form wouldn't recognize it as type=submit.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it through an Event Listener

```
var form 
form.addEventListener( 'submit', function(e){
    alert("test")
});
```

Comment: I have tried this but the event is never triggered.